# RAID 5/10 setup

Tags: raid, nas, raid-5

I am trying to setup a personal media server. I am thinking of working with RAID 5 or 10 ( I haven't decided yet). So my questions are

1. What would be a recommended RAID setup? I don't need anything fancy as long as I can recover lost data if any of the HDDs fail.
2. Do I have to setup the RAID at once? What I mean by that is, if I plan on setting up my final RAID setup of 5x 4TB RAID 5 (giving me 15 TB to use and 5 TB for parity) do I have to get all 5 HDDs at once and set them up at first boot or I can add them as time goes? (I think I will have to get 2x4TB to get things started).

Any answers will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you need RAID 10 - RAID5 will not work reliably for the volume of data you are trying to store - ie the risk of the second disk failing while a failed disk rebuilding is very high - and [RAID5 is not recommended](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/RAID-5-Doomed-2009,6525.html) for this size disk.

As to whether you have to set up your RAID at once - that cant be answered definitively without information about your specific RAID hardware and software, but some controllers and [only some software RAID setups will allow you to do this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/grow-lvm-raid10).  Its thus a good idea to set the whole thing up initially.

If you are using Linux and software RAID, you might want to look at using a RAID1 2 disk setup and LVM.  You can then purchase another 2 disks, create a second RAID1 array and use LVM to merge the 2 RAID disks into a single large disk.